# Detect parent's flexDirection

Tags: react-native

Is it possible to detect parent's flexDirection to style the children accordingly?

For example, the `Button` component stretches to fill all the horizzontal width if the parent container has `flexDirection: column`, instead, if the parent container has `flexDirection: row` the `Button` component will occupy just the space to contain the text inside the button. So, it seems as the `Button` component detects the parent container's `flexDirection` and it reacts accordingly.

How can I achive something like this with my own component?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe the best approach is to make a custom component for that button and pass the desired direction as a prop!